# Small furry alien but very intelligent and good fighter with human male partner

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel, space

I'm trying to find the name of a short story or novel from the '60s to early '80s.

The human and the alien partner travel in space, solving mysteries or fighting bad guys or just getting rich. The alien's cute looks lead to him being underestimated by opponents. He also does not like being petted by random children who see him.

It could have been by Poul Anderson or someone similar to that. We were reading him and Niven and Pournelle in those days.

Comment: The Poul Anderson stories about David Falkayn include his companion Chee, a small catlike alien who dislikes being petted by children. Could that be it? There is one other alien (Adzel, a large reptilian being) in the group which is why I don't write it as an answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: how could it not be?

Comment: @OrganicMarble You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you. This has been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: The one thing I remember most clearly about Chee is when she tells the mother of a child who just petted her that it is a shame that humans don't eat their young.

Comment: Compared to a Hutt....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, David Falkayn and Chee Lan must be the ones. I found this quote on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/638985):

> Chee Lan, a dog like alien, female, with a sharp tongue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It would have been polite to answer my comment and let me post the answer, since I am the one who suspected what it was.